# Special base of 1-chains

Tags: graph-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $\Gamma$ be a graph and $\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n\}$ be a maximal set of linearly independent closed paths in $\Gamma$.  Let $z\in Z_1(\Gamma)$ be a 1-cycle in $\Gamma$.  How can I show that $z$ is a combination of the closed paths $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}$?

Note: the chain module I'm considering has real coefficients, so it is actually a vector space.

Comment: Does this not follow from the fact than any maximal independent set of a finite dimensional vector space is a basis of the vector space?

Comment: Since this question seems to attract very little attention, I suggest changing the tags, and possibly adding a little background. Right now, the most active tag for this question is [tag:graph-theory], but most users browsing this tag don't know what a chain module is. (Also, what does it mean for paths in a graph to be closed, or linearly independent?)